# Windows 10 not waking from sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I've noticed after updating Windows on my Asus notebook (`x555u`) that Windows has problems when I try to exit sleep mode. The screen flashs to different black colors infinitely, so I need to power off my computer (by pressing start button a long time) to start it again. I don't know what's wrong, I've tried to update my NVIDIA drivers (`GPU`) but the problem is still occuring.

Comment: did you try disabling hibernation? launch Command prompt with admin rights (right click on start button) powercfg /h off and reboot you pc

Comment: I've alerdy tried that, not working